# In a GeoTiff, what unit are extents in?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, extents, units

I was looking at the GDAL metadata of a USGS GeoTiff quad (o48118e8) with the GdalToTilesWin program. It dumped the following info:

```
Name o48118e8.tif
Size X/Y 5315/6780
ResolutionX/Y 2.4384/2.4384
Extent
North 5388204.0171
West 350547.3487
South 5371671.6651
East 363507.4447
It is not Geodesic WGS84(EPSG:4326)
PROJCS[
    "NAD27 / UTM zone 11N",
    GEOGCS[
        "NAD27",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",
        SPHEROID[
            "Clarke 1866",
            6378206.4,
            294.9786982139006,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]
        ],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-117],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT[
        "metre",
        1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]
    ],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26711"]
]
```

Could someone explain how to understand extent? For instance, does `North 5388204.0171` mean 5388204.0171 meters north of the NAD27?

Or maybe the `Unit.Metre` has something to do with it?

How do these 'extents' convert to lat/long (if at all?)

Also, out of curiosity, I presume the `SizeX/Y` is pixels, but what is the `ResolutionX/Y`?

Comment: it's in metres. The first part is the geographic datum it's based on, the second part is the projection (Transverse Mercator)... your coordinate system is EPSG:26711 (NAD27 UTM Zone 11n http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad27-utm-zone-11n/) size X/Y is how many cells, resolution X/Y is how big the cells are 'on the ground', your extent is that box in that coordinate system. Spatial reference of a raster is (usually) given by a 6 parameter transformation (of which two are usually 0) which boils down to upper left X,Y and Cell size X, Y - both in units of the spatial reference.

Comment: And the origin of the coordinate system is defined with the latitude of origin and central meridian parameters. In addition, false easting reveals that 500000 meters is added to east-west coordinate. Meaning of this is to keep the numbers positive also to the west of the central meridian.

Comment: It makes maths *much* easier if there are no negative numbers.. this is the whole point of false easting and false northing. That said, the Y cellsize is almost always negative, which makes coding a bit of a challenge. When you have a cell size but not a spatial reference it's a bit more difficult.. geographic cell sizes are tiny, so you can assume DD if the numbers are like 0.00002, metres are big (like 1, 2, 2.5) but so are feet, I'd assume metres but look at the graphic against known to be accurate data just to be sure - if it's really feet then it would be quite obvious not where it should

Answer (score 2):

The units of the extent will inherit from the units of the projection of the data, so to convert the extent to lat/long, you would need to reproject your data to a geographic projection (usually WGS1984) that uses degrees as units. Your data appears to have been projected to NAD27 / UTM zone 11N, which has units of meters. The extent refers to the x and y values in the projection of the furthest N, S, E, and W points (or ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax) in the layer, forming a box around it. So, visually:

```
            5388204.0171
          |----------------|     and,       350547.3487  |                | 363507.4447
          |----------------|
            5371671.6651
```

would define the spatial extent of the file. Sometimes the extent is expressed in terms of the coordinates of the corners of the box around the layer. In your case, the upper left corner would be: (350547.3487, 5388204.0171) and so on.

Also, the resolution refers to the x and y length, in units of your projection, of each pixel in the raster and the size is the number of rows and columns (number of pixels in the x and y directions)